# Pass data from one component to all with $emit without using @click in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

Trying to learn vuejs I got to the question how to pass any data from one component to all, using $emit but without using any @click. 
It is possible some how that the data to be just available and grab it any time, without using the click?

Let's say we have this example with normal @click and $emit.

main.js

```
export const eventBus = new Vue()
```

Hello.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>This is Hello component</h2>
    <button 
      @click="emitGlobalClickEvent()">Click me</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { eventBus } from '../main'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    emitGlobalClickEvent () {
      eventBus.$emit('messageSelected', this.msg)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

User.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>This is User component</h2>
    <user-one></user-one>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import { eventBus } from '../main'
  import UserOne from './UserOne.vue'
  export default {
    created () {
      eventBus.$on('messageSelected', msg => {
        console.log(msg)
      })
    },
    components: {
      UserOne
    }
  }
</script>
```

UserOne.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
      <h3>We are in UserOne component</h3>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import { eventBus } from '../main'
  export default {
    created () {
      eventBus.$on('messageSelected', msg => {
        console.log('From UserOne message !!!')
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

I want to get this message : Welcome to Your Vue.js App from Hello.vue in all components, but without @click, if is possible.

Comment: The usual way to make data available to children is via [props](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props)

Comment: Just use Vuex. Create vuex store with data, inject it to vue instance and in all components you can read these data as this.$store - no need for props anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another Javascript file which holds an Object with your initial state. Similar to how you define data in your components.

In this file your export your Object and import it in all Components which need access to this shared state. Something along the lines of this:

```
import Store from 'store';

data() {
  return {
    store
  }
}
```

This might help:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html

At this point if you app grows even more in complexity you might also start checking out Vuex which helps to keep track of changes(mutations) inside of your store.

The given example is essential a very oversimplified version of Vuex.